# How to set up new types for pattern matching strings?

Tags: string-manipulation, pattern-matching

Consider the following toy example: I have a set of language sounds, which I partition into two exclusive subsets, consonants and vowels. I want to set up string patterns for e.g. `StringMatchQ` that may contain restrictions based on the sound specification. For sake of simplicity, I used letters instead of sounds, as for now it does not matter.

```
(* Define domains *)
vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
consonants = {"b", "c", "d", "f", "g"};

(* Define predicates *)
VowelQ[x_] := MemberQ[vowels, x];
ConsonantQ[x_] := MemberQ[consonants, x];

(* Use predicates in pattern matcher *)
StringReplace["badge", 
 Shortest[pre__] ~~ c : __?ConsonantQ ~~ v_?VowelQ ~~ EndOfString :> 
  pre <> "-[" <> c <> "]-[" <> v <> "]"]
```

> `"ba-[dg]-[e]"`

My question is:

**How to set up domains that can be used like e.g. `DigitCharacter` in the pattern matcher**,

that is, how to define `Consonant` and `Vowel` in the following (putative) application to yield the same result as the above code?

```
StringReplace["badge", 
 Shortest[pre__] ~~ c : Consonant .. ~~ v : Vowel ~~ EndOfString :> 
  pre <> "-[" <> c <> "]-[" <> v <> "]"]
```

I can define new data structures, like `Consonant["c"]`, that is displayed as `"c"`, but is nevertheless interpreted as `Consonant["c"]`, though I have the feeling that this is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to use lexical environments, in particular the function `makeCustomEnvironment` which I posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768651/how-to-define-constants-for-use-with-with-in-one-place-and-then-apply-them-lat/8769688#8769688)

```
ClearAll[makeCustomEnvironment];
SetAttributes[makeCustomEnvironment, HoldAll];
makeCustomEnvironment[values : (_Symbol = _) ..] := 
      Function[code, With @@ Hold[{values}, code], HoldAll];
```

now, define a custom environment:

```
env = makeCustomEnvironment[Consonant = _?ConsonantQ, Vowel = _?VowelQ]
```

And use it:

```
env@StringReplace["badge",
    Shortest[pre__]~~c:Consonant..~~v:Vowel~~EndOfString:>pre<>"-["<>c<>"]-["<>v<>"]"]

(*
  ==> "ba-[dg]-[e]"
*)
```

Note that the literals `Consonant` and `Vowel` don't acquire any global values, and have special meaning only for the code literally present inside the `env` environment. You can view this solution as a simple example of Mathematica meta-programming.

**EDIT**

Another alternative (which I like less, but still) is to use `UpValues`:

```
ClearAll[Consonant, Vowel]
Consonant /: f_[left___, Consonant, right___] := 
    f[left, _?ConsonantQ, right];
Vowel /: f_[left___, Vowel, right___] := f[left, _?VowelQ, right];
```

In this case, you can run your code without any wrappers, but I personally would still go for local environments (note that I defined the above pretty carelessly for any `f` - for example, you won't be able to `Clear` `Consonant` or `Vowel` easily now. If you choose this method, you may want to narrow the set of `f`-s in the above).

And of course, you can just simply use assignments

```
ClearAll[Consonant, Vowel]
Consonant = _?ConsonantQ;
Vowel     = _?VowelQ;
```

but this will likely exclude the use of symbols `Consonant` and  `Vowel` in other capacities in some other pieces of your code, since they now have global values. This may also not work if they are used inside functions which hold their arguments, since they are replaced by their values as a result of their evaluation, in this method.

Comment: Very useful, as usual! Now since I want to package the whole `Consonant`/`Vowel` thing with a lot more, it seems reasonable to use `UpValues` instead of the environment wrapper, for deployment. What are the drawbacks of `UpValues` compared to `makeCustomEnvironment`?

Comment: @Istvan The main drawback is that `UpValues` create global effects (although localized in certain sense, but still), so they may fire in some unforeseen cases. This will be less of an issue if you put your `Consonant` and `Vowel` into some package (namespace). But, you may have some unexpected behavior *in your own* code, like e.g. above, where you can't easily clear them. If you package this stuff with a lot more, you probably can use `env` (local environments) internally, hiding them behind some interface function, so the user won't see them (and I'd think this is cleaner than `UpValues`).